# render an action view using ajax with js.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

inside show.js.erb

```
$('#viewport').html("<%= escape_javascript(render('show')) %>");
```

I am trying to render the show view into the bottom of the index view. Show is not a partial.
This doesn't work. But I'm sure this page gets executed because I tried something like 'hello world', and it gets rendered.

other things i did are:

added a div #viewport inside index view

added remote: true in the links inside index view

added render js { :layout => false } inside the controller's show action

Comment: are you getting any error? JS error? 500 error?

Comment: how do i check that? I don't think there's any frontend error, i think something's wrong with the way i do the render in js.erb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert show view into a partial. Move the source inside show.html into a file named _view.html.erb:

```
$('#viewport').html("<%= escape_javascript(render('view')) %>");
```

Show.html.erb became:

```
render('view')
```

Comment: tail -f log/development.log in your root directory.

Comment: got it now, the problem was missing local variable. But I really want it to be non-partial view though, is there any way to do it?